# Java cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java

Hello when I run my code I'm getting "java: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called" error. How can I fix this?

```
public class Premiumhosting extends Hosting{
public int Hosting_fee=0;

public boolean setsignupFeePaid;
public Premiumhosting(String server, String website, String livesupport, String siteDomain, int ram, boolean sethostingFeePaid) {
    super(server, website, livesupport, siteDomain, ram, this.Hosting_fee);
    this.sethostingFeePaid=sethostingFeePaid;
}

public double calculateRam(double purchaseAmount){
    if(sethostingFeePaid){
        return (5*purchaseAmount);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`this.Hosting_fee` is not initialized yet and cannot be - it is therefore always 0. If your code had worked, replacing `this.Hosting_fee` with `0` would have done the same thing. What are you trying to accomplish? If it's just 'pass 0', then.. just replace `this.Hosting_fee` with `0`. If that wasn't your intent, perhaps update the question or ask a new one, I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are more classes which have different Hosting fees like public int Hosting_fee=5; etc

Comment: fields do not get overridden, you merely shadow them. They aren't like methods. It is not possible for Hosting_fee to mean anything but 0 in this code. Not just 'that is what happens', but in the more fundamental sense - that code (`this.hosting_fee`) is a reference to that precise field.